# How to internationalize a Select Menu

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, react-intl

In my React application with Antd internationalized with react-intl I have a select component as follows, but when the page language is changed the select options do not change language.

```
const TicketCategorySelect: React.FC = () => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const [ticketCategories, setTicketCategories] = useState<TicketCategory[]>(
    []
  );

  const getTicketCategories = async () => {
    try {
      let { data } = await ticketService.getTicketCategories();
      setTicketCategories(data);
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    void getTicketCategories();
  }, [parentId]);

  return (
    <Form.Item
      name={name}
      label={intl.formatMessage({
        id: 'ticketCategoryLabel',
      })}
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'errorRequired',
          }),
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Select
        placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
          id: 'ticketCategoryLabel',
        })}
        options={ticketCategories
          .map(({ id, name }) => ({
            label: intl.formatMessage({
              id: name,
            }),
            value: id.toString(),
          }))}
      />
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

export default TicketCategorySelect;
```

I tried to bind the mapping of the options to a state and update it every time the locale changes but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

The answer is relatively simple, on the language change, the react doesn't have a clue that it has happened. In functional components you would normally use `hooks`.

Luckily for you there's already a `react-intl` package and allows you to get the translations through `formattedMessage` here

https://github.com/CreateThrive/react-intl-hooks#useformatmessage

I haven't used it myself, but assuming this would help in your case. Especially since it's using a Context Provider it should be able to respond to those changes.